# Moving a legacy .NET App: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-2.0

I've got a problem moving a legacy web application based on .NET 2.0 and written in C#, to a new Windows 2012 Foundation Server. IIS 7.0 is already configured in ASP.NET classic mode.

Almost all pages are showing the following error.

I'd like to know what is the part of the source code that is generating this error, but the message displays `[No relevant source lines]`.

Do you have some ideas?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

    [No relevant source lines]  

    Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\813bde8d\3a1aaa6a\App_Web_uc_elencoviaggi.ascx.572aee0e.phamg6cd.0.cs    Line: 0

    Stack Trace:  

            [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]


 Makr.UI.PagamentiDataContext..ctor() +28
   Makr.UI.Viaggi.UC_ElencoViaggi..ctor() +26
   ASP.viaggi_uc_elencoviaggi_ascx..ctor() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\813bde8d\3a1aaa6a\App_Web_uc_elencoviaggi.ascx.572aee0e.phamg6cd.0.cs:0
   ASP.amministrazione_elencoviaggi_aspx.__BuildControlUC_ElencoViaggi1() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp_Makr_Contabilita\Amministrazione\ElencoViaggi.aspx:6
   ASP.amministrazione_elencoviaggi_aspx.__BuildControlContent2(Control __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp_Makr_Contabilita\Amministrazione\ElencoViaggi.aspx:5
   System.Web.UI.CompiledTemplateBuilder.InstantiateIn(Control container) +12
   ASP.master_amministrazione_master.__BuildControlContentPlaceHolder1() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp_Makr_Contabilita\Master\Amministrazione.Master:150
   ASP.master_amministrazione_master.__BuildControlform1() in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp_Makr_Contabilita\Master\Amministrazione.Master:13
   ASP.master_amministrazione_master.__BuildControlTree(master_amministrazione_master __ctrl) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebApp_Makr_Contabilita\Master\Amministrazione.Master:1
   ASP.master_amministrazione_master.FrameworkInitialize() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\813bde8d\3a1aaa6a\App_Web_9f0g2exr.0.cs:0
   System.Web.UI.UserControl.InitializeAsUserControlInternal() +35
   System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner, HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary contentTemplateCollection) +8696687
   System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master() +51
   System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage() +15
   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +45
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +282
```

Here is the code of the page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" EnableEventValidation="false" Theme="default" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Amministrazione.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ElencoViaggi.aspx.cs" Inherits="Makr.UI.Amministrazione.ElencoViaggi" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ Register src="../Viaggi/UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx" tagname="UC_ElencoViaggi" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <uc1:UC_ElencoViaggi ID="UC_ElencoViaggi1" runat="server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is .NET 2.0 installed?

Comment: 99% sure it is, taking into account the path `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\` in the exception.

Comment: I think yes, during the installation of IIS 7.0, It's v. 2.0.50727. However, could be the wrong version? How can I find what is the right .NET version to use?

Comment: Ignore the .NET 2.0 version, I don't think that's the cause of your exception. That version number - `2.0.50727` - is the same on my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the exception, it mentions an `ascx` file. Can you view the source code of the ASP.NET app and see if there is an `ascx` file used in a master page, or at least used in the `aspx` pages?

It looks like that `ascx` is doing something with an object and that object is null. Without seeing the code, it could be any reason why the object is null.

Comment: I added the code of the page; but the error says "At line :0"... And actually I don't know for real where could be the root cause of the error. Also, I'm not a Microsoft developer.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx`. Try removing that ascx from the aspx page and try the site again. Does it work this time? Remove the lines that use ` <uc1:` since that is the ascx control.

Comment: No, it generates another error: `Line 6: <uc1:UC_ElencoViaggi ID="UC_ElencoViaggi1" runat="server" />`. However I think that this is the core of the page.

Comment: I just tried, it compiles without errors, but the page is useless, because of only the skeleton of the master page is displayed.
I find this parameter in the `ascx` page: `CodeBehind="UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx.cs"`. But the file `UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx.cs` doesn't exists. Could be this the problem?

Comment: No you know 100% that the problem is with `UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx`. So now, you need to open the file `UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx.cs` and figure out what the problem is. Try commenting out some code and then removing the comments to see where the code breaks. Can you post the source code for `UC_ElencoViaggi.ascx.cs` but only if you are allowed to do so? As in, the source code is not private property of anyone.

Comment: Yeah, I could publish the code... but I don't have any `.cs` file in my server. This project was restored from the backup of crashed production server, so I'm near to end up that the application can't run anymore because the source code is incomplete. Right? However, thanks for your support Jason.

Comment: Ahh :( That makes things a lot more difficult. You could look into using WinDbg to look at the crash e.g. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892277   but this is a very advanced method which may take a bit of learning first.